# Configuring Quartz.net Tasks

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I want to be able to set up one or more Jobs/Triggers when my app runs.  The list of Jobs and triggers will come from a db table.  I DO NOT care about persisting the jobs to the db for restarting or tracking purposes.  Basically I just want to use the DB table as an INIt device.  Obviously I can do this by writing the code myself but I am wondering if there is some way to use the SQLJobStore to get this functionality without the overhead of keeping the db updated throughout the life of the app using the scheduler.

Thanks for you help!
Eric

Answer (score 0):

The job store's main purpose is to store the scheduler's state, so there is no way built in to do what you want. You can always write directly to the tables if you want and this will give you the results you want, but this isn't really the best way to do it.

The recommended way to do this would be to write some code that reads the data from your table and then connects to the scheduler using remoting to schedule the jobs.